# My java swing timer is limited to a +- 300ms schedule

Tags: java, swing, timer

So I set up an Arduino as a JSON server, which's data I'd then like to log in a .log file on my desktop. The problem however is that the timer (javax.swing.timer) wont't work with any value longer than about +- 300ms. The rest of the code works fine, but maybe the JSON library has some influence on the timer? I'd be glad if someone were to help. The program does execute, and it doesn't show any error when I'm compiling it. This is most of the code, and I've marked the place where I think it fails with some asterisks:

```
    public class ikd {

  private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      return json;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
      getData();
  }

  public static void getData() throws IOException, JSONException {
      //***********************************************
      //***********************************************
      ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
              System.out.println("yea");
          }
      };
      new Timer(>+-300 works here but 400 doesn't!!!<, taskPerformer).start();  
      //***********************************************
      //***********************************************
      JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl(">");
      System.out.println(json.toString());
      JSONArray arr = json.getJSONArray("kamers");
      JSONObject tempObj = (JSONObject)arr.get(0);
      String temp = tempObj.getString("temp");
      String humidity = tempObj.getString("humidity");
      String light = tempObj.getString("ldr");
      System.out.println("Temperatuur: " + temp + ", Luchtvochtigheid: " + humidity + ", Lichtsterkte: " + light);
      try{
          PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("data.log", "UTF-8");
          writer.println(temp + "," + humidity + "," + light);
          writer.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
  }
```

If I put the timer in the Main() method,nothing happens at all.

This is the console output with the timer running at 301 ms intervals:

301 ms interval:

[image: 301 ms interval]

And this is the console output at a 400 ms interval:

400 ms interval:

[image: 400 ms interval]

Comment: Sorry, but -1 for this type of code: `catch (Exception e) {}`. This is not just dumb code, it's downright dangerous code, and the same for try/finally without a catch. At least catch and display your exceptions with `e.printStacktrace();`.

Comment: My guess: you're throwing an exception and have no idea that it's happening. Please prove me wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry hadn't changed it there. Yes, that was kind of stupid, but I was just tinkering around removing / moving around some things to see what might have any effect at all. I ofcourse have used e.printStacktrace(); before, but it didn't respond with any error at all.

Comment: Please show your code that shows you handling exceptions. Also best if you could drill the problem down to its essence and post a valid [mcve]. This will require debugging and isolating on your part.

Comment: Why are you using Swing timer? java.util.Timer might be better if you don't have a Swing UI.

Comment: That's what a MCVE would prove -- is he in fact creating a Swing GUI?

Comment: I am using the Swing timer because I will probably add 2d graphing in a JFrame later on, and maybe a visualization of the then current temperature.

Comment: Then that may be your problem since without a Swing GUI the event thread may stop. Create your GUI and see if it works with the GUI in place.